# How to set FontSize in pt if we use StaticResource or DynamicResource?

Tags: wpf

currently i am using fontsize resource as

```
 <sys:Double x:Key="FontSize13">13</sys:Double>
<sys:Double x:Key="FontSize12">12</sys:Double>
<sys:Double x:Key="FontSize11">11</sys:Double>
```

and using as

```
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="{DynamicResource FontSize13}" />
```

How to set the FontSize in point like 10pt instead of pixel?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The type conversion happens at compile time by the XAML compiler and specifically in response to the `FontSizeConverter` being present for the `FontSize` property so we have a basic problem getting the converter to run.  But we can create a helper markup extension to do the job.

Here's what the XAML looks like:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:FontSize Size="20" x:Key="TwentyPixels"/>
        <local:FontSize Size="11pt" x:Key="ElevenPoint"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Sample text" FontSize="{StaticResource TwentyPixels}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Sample text" FontSize="{StaticResource ElevenPoint}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and here's the markup extension:

```
public class FontSizeExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(FontSizeConverter))]
    public double Size { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Size;
    }
}
```

Comment: without extension, there is no way to do that in XAML resource itself?

Comment: I tried to think of a way, but could not.  You can do terrible things like define a text block in static resources with a font size and then refer to that font size but that is not what you want.

Comment: Thnx for the extension method. Excellent

Answer (score -1):

Just use a space between number and "pt". For example:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11 pt"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score -3):

Just changed the resource from a Double to a String and include the unit specifier

```
<sys:String x:Key="FontSize13">13pt</sys:String>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that throws an ArgumentException at runtime.