# WPF How to set pt(12pt etc..) via DynamicResource for FontSize property

Tags: wpf, binding, font-size, dynamicresource

I can use:

```
<TextBlock Text="Some Textes" FontSize="12pt" />
```

It works normally. But I want to use the `DynamicResource` extension, is it possible?

This does not work:

```
<TextBlock Text="Some Textes" FontSize="{DynamicResource SomeResources}" />
```

SomeResources:

```
<System:Stringx:Key="SomeResources">12pt</System:String>
```

I do not want to use an `AttachedBehavior`. I know, I can solve my problem with it (using `FontSizeConverter`).

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

I see you've edited your question and taken out the binding option. If your only wanting to get this from a xaml resource, you'd need to use a `MarkupExtension`. You can find the `MarkupExtension` and the usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907020/how-to-set-fontsize-in-pt-if-we-use-staticresource-or-dynamicresource). This will work fine for your case.

*Orig reply:*

`FontSize` is of type `System:Double` [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.fontsize%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Next default `Binding` for `FontSize` assumes pixels at device independent scale but since you need pt's we can use a converter such as:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

class ConvertFromPoint : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    var convertFrom = new FontSizeConverter().ConvertFrom(value.ToString());
    if (convertFrom != null)
      return (double) convertFrom;
    return 1;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

and usage:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="{Binding StringProperty, Converter={StaticResource ConvertFromPointConverter}}">Some Text</TextBlock>
```

**Alternate:**

If you do not want to use converters and `FontSizeConverter` just do the calculation in your property getter.

something like:

```
private double _someFontval;
public double SomeFontVal {
  get {
    return _someFontval * 96 / 72;
  }

  set {
    _someFontval = value;
  }
}
```

usage:

```
//.cs
SomeFontVal = 12.0;

//.xaml
<TextBlock FontSize="{Binding SomeFontVal}">Some Text</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just bind it as a <strike>int</strike> double

```
<System:Double x:Key="SomeResources">12</System:Double>
```

Comment: 12 and 12pt are different for WPF.
12 * (96/72) = 12pt as far as I know.
for 96dpi comp.

Comment: Ahh, wasn't aware of that. In that case, I don't know a way to do it without the `FontSizeConverter` you mentioned